# What character set / encoding does the windows event log use?

Tags: windows, character-encoding, event-log

**Background:**

I'm working on a solution which will include writing data from multiple countries and reading from to the windows event log (e.g. if there's an exception processing a customer record I may include the customer's name in the description text to make it more human readable; customers' names are likely to require special characters from their language - and we will never take Prince as a customer).
I'm writing and reading as various systems in our business are writing whilst I'm defining the monitoring system which will be reading from & working with event log data.

I've looked on Google but can't find any relevant information on this.
Looking at the XML view of Events there's no file header / encoding attribute defined.
I'd assume it's UTF-8 in the later versions, but can't find this documented / would be surprised if older versions supported that encoding.

**Questions:**

- What character set is used by the Windows Event Log?
- Is it the same for all versions of Windows?

Comment: All Windows winapi functions and internal data structures use utf-16 encoded strings, so does the event log.  You could only get into trouble by using the legacy ReportEventA() function.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks Hans.  If you put that in an answer I'll tick you the points. JB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per `Hans Passant`'s comment:

> All Windows winapi functions and internal data structures use utf-16
>   encoded strings, so does the event log. You could only get into
>   trouble by using the legacy ReportEventA() function.

Comment: A relevant link to documentation would be helpful. I found this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Intl/unicode but would hope for something more explicit...